# Why do my API requests to my Vercel hosted API get received as a GET instead of a POST? Is there some kind of authorization I need to account for?

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, fetch, vercel

I am trying to host a personal portfolio website on Vercel with a Python/Flask backend and React frontend. In development, running these on my local machine I was able to use my front end component to interact with the backend API. Now that both are hosted on Vercel, I am unable to do so.

I initially used the normal JavaScript fetch tool, but then tried Axios when it wasn't working for me. Neither is working for me. The front end tells me that the POST request failed, and the backend tells me there's a 404 error and it's receiving a GET request. When I try to use Postman to make a request instead, it correctly tells me that it received a POST request, but gives a 401 error.

Here is my post request:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
const resp = await axios.post(import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL +'/contact', {
            'email': email,
            'message': message
        }, config)
```

VITE_BACKEND_URL (not currently deployed since it wasn't working for me):

```
VITE_BACKEND_URL=https://personal-portfolio-p7a3ypu2j-johnd42s-projects.vercel.app
```

Here is my flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import ssl
import smtplib
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

load_dotenv()

CORS(app)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, this is my API! You can't do anything with it from this link."

@app.route('/contact', methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])
def contact():
    req = request.get_json()
    email = req['email']
    message = req['message']
    if message is None:
        return jsonify({"msg": "No message was provided."}), 400
    if email is None:
        return jsonify({"msg": "No email was provided."}), 400
    
    print(os.environ)
    EMAIL_SENDER = os.getenv('EMAIL_SENDER')
    print(EMAIL_SENDER)
    EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
    print(EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    email_receiver = 'johndurtka@gmail.com'
    email_body = f"Message from {email}: {message}"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_SENDER
    msg['To'] = email_receiver
    msg['Subject'] = 'Contact from Personal Portfolio Website'

    msg.attach(MIMEText(email_body, 'plain'))

    port = 587  # For starttls
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.login(EMAIL_SENDER, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        server.send_message(msg)
    return "Message sent!", 200 

@app.before_request 
def before_request(): 
    headers = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type' } 
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS' or request.method == 'options': 
        return jsonify(headers), 200
```

Here are some of my logs on Vercel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D9VS.png)
Here is my console when I try to make the fetch request from my front end hosted on Vercel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jToIO.png)

What is causing my POST requests to be received as GET requests? Also, does Vercel use some kind of JWT authentication system such that I need to be sending an authorization header in my requests? If so, where can I find the token or set it up?

Thank you for any help! This is the first website I have actually tried to host on Vercel so I don't know how it works at all.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with Vercel itself, it wasn't built for backend deployments.

I faced a similar issue while hosting an ExpressJS backend on the platform. It was solved by hosting the API on Cyclic.sh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I will look into other options for hosting the backend.